# What are the drop rates for items in pots?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

Does anyone know the drop rate for items in pots in *The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time*? I found a table for basically everything else ([here](https://i.redditmedia.com/5nlmOOlYDoUIWr66kIvzKTLNWYRfCP4DAGOJZ5vrPbk.png?s=adda4536535cee06ca379b811b8a4452) if you're interested) but it doesn't include most pots. I know some pots drop the same thing every time (for instance, there's one pot in Goron City that always drops a Deku Stick), but I'm looking for just in general. I also don't really care about the flying pots because those aren't all over the place.

Comment: Are you sure any of them are at all random?

Comment: Pretty sure some of them at least are somewhat random. Like, if you go into the guardhouse as a child and break all the pots you can walk out with anywhere between 25-35 rupees. Though I suppose it's possible each individual pot or group of pots has its own drop table, which is why nobody's bothered to find drop tables for them.

Answer (score 5):

According to [speedruns.com](https://www.speedrun.com/oot/guide/prwj5), this is the drop table for everything in the game. Enemies and pots included.

[image]

Comment: So does a pot fall into the same category as grass, then? Because I feel like I've read this chart about 16 times at this point and I don't see anything about pots.

Comment: Yeah I think you got it. Anything that's not an enemy falls under the same part of the table is how I read it.

Comment: @MikeG Correct, there is nothing about pots here, since in Ocarina of Time they do not have random drops.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the creator of the drop table you linked. Pots in Ocarina of Time are 100% hardcoded, they should always drop the same item.

What you'll find is some pots use a room flag and others use a dungeon flag to mark whether their item has been grabbed or not, dungeon flag pots will not give you the same item again until you exit and re-enter the dungeon.

Majora's Mask is different, and actually does occasionally use drop tables for some pots, which tables they use though vary from pot to pot.

If you're interested, OoTMap.com, my Ocarina of Time Interactive Map, features a Containers tab where you can see what every pot and box in the game is set to drop.